# ElasticSearch: I want to get in clause and group by together

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for ElasticSearch equivalent of below query -
SELECT * FROM test where school in ('avm') group by name
id name school
1 amit avm 
2 amit avm 
3 sanjeev pvm 
4 ravi avm

id name school 
1 amit avm 
4 ravi avm 
I want to result like this using elasticsearch. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it using aggregation. E.g. to get `SELECT name, COUNT(*)` you will do something like this

```
{
  "size": 0, // to keep your output clean from actual search results
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to count.i want to list of name group by with in clause..thanks for your reply

Comment: Still. It's not perfectly clear what you want to find in columns other than `name`? You want to fund random value of this column there? Or values in some specific order? It all can be done using aggregations, `top_hits`, probably, but I need to know more to help you figure it out